# Kernow: SXXP0003: Error reported by XML parser: Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: xml

When I try to upload the following xml document into Kernow, I get the following error:

```
Error on line 1 column 1 of file:/Users/rdp/Desktop/Kernow/:
  SXXP0003: Error reported by XML parser: Content is not allowed in prolog.
javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Failed to compile stylesheet. 1 error detected.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Single File" upload requires a stylesheet, which I didn't give it. I just wanted to try out some XQuery queries on an XML file, and I could do that easily by copying the xml file into the Kernow directory, and running the queries in the XQuery Sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is complaining about the stylesheet, not the source document, so I don't know why you chose to show us the source document.

The error message "Content is not allowed in prolog" from Xerces can cover a large number of different situations that prevented parsing getting underway: it can be an empty file, an incorrect encoding, whitespace or newlines before the XML declaration, an input file that simply isn't XML, etc. Sometimes it means that the source document being read isn't the source document you intended. The file name given in the error message suggests to me that it might be trying to parse a directory.